# How to create .aspx page in Runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create .aspx page at runtime:

Say for Ex:

I have a configuration xml file, it has 2 main nodes and each has its subnodes as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
<Options name="First">
    <controls>
        <control type="textbox" lable="Option1TextBox" value="">            
    </controls>
</Options>

<Options name="Second">
    <controls>
        <control type="textbox" lable="Option2TextBox" value="">
        <control type="dropdown" lable="Option2dropdown" value="Value1, Value2">            
    </controls>
</Options>
```

1. When i load the .aspx page, i have to read the xml file  node and i take the "name" attribute and create the dropdownlist control in the page.
2. From the dropdownlist, if the user selects the "First" i need to loop through the subnode  and create the controls at runtime in the same aspx page. EX: If the user selects "First" from the drop down, i need to create a Texbox in the page. and If the user selects "Second" from the drop down, i need to create a Textbox and dropdown list as given in the xml.

Any suggestion/guide will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating an "aspx" page at the run time, you should look into creating [User Control for ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then adding them at run time according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some steps to achive what you want.

1. [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) xml.
2. Subscribe on `DropDownList` `SelectedIndexChanged` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx).
3. Add code that will [add controls to the page dynamicaly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx).